# How to manually do a TCP handshake

Tags: networking, internet, connection, tcp, telnet

Telnet can be used to manually do things that programs do automatically. When I connect to a server I noticed that it automatically does the 3-way handshake to establish a TCP connection. Can it be done manually in telnet? If not, then what program can do it?

Comment: Could you explain why this is needed?

Comment: I'm learning about TCP/IP and there is a server that has been set up that I can experiment with.

Comment: You can use with `nmap -sS` family instead of scapy, scapy has been used for writing exploit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If by "manually" you mean "instruct `telnet` to send SYN and ACK packets", then no. This is done by the operating system, which needs to keep track of all TCP parameters for a connection – sequence numbers, window size, etc.

It *would* be possible for a program to use raw IP sockets and manage the TCP layer all by itself. But it's generally an incredibly pointless thing to do – it would copy *a lot* of code from kernel.

If you are trying to learn how TCP works, try [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/). It can create and send packets using given parameters, including TCP. (You'll probably have to use a packet sniffer to watch for such things as SYN+ACK though.)

Answer (score 1):

The book "TCP/IP Illustrated, Volume 1" by Stevens explains what goes on in creating and using a TCP connection.  Yes, it has been around a while ( (c) 1994 ) but sometimes the explanations given when a technology is new have more depth than anything that comes after.

To see the details of what is happening on the wire a copy of Wireshark (http://www.wireshark.org) is what you need. When you understand how a header and message are structured and packed wireshark shows you the structure and you can drill down to the bit fields.